# Qiskit Runtime forbids reset gate?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, qiskit-runtime

Some parts of my quantum circuit uses `initialize` to prepare specific amplitudes to the qubits. However, the Qiskit Runtime outputs error:

```
"Unable to retrieve job result. HighLevelSynthesis was unable to synthesize Instruction(name='reset', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]). -- Verify the input circuits and the traspilation options. -- https://ibm.biz/error_codes#1516"
```

Could it be because `initialize` function contains `reset` which is not unitary. If so, how can one initialize specific complex amplitudes to the qubits in Qiskit runtime?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the problem is that `initialize` introduces a `reset` ([see docs](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit#initialize)).

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.initialize('11', [0, 1], normalize=False)
circuit.decompose().draw()
```

```
          ┌─────────────────────────┐
q_0: ─|0>─┤0                        ├
          │  State Preparation(1,1) │
q_1: ─|0>─┤1                        ├
          └─────────────────────────┘
       ^
here is the reset
```

You have two options.

**Option 1**: Remove the resets in the front:

```python
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import RemoveResetInZeroState
circuit = RemoveResetInZeroState()(circuit.decompose())
circuit.draw()
```

```
     ┌─────────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                        ├
     │  State Preparation(1,1) │
q_1: ┤1                        ├
     └─────────────────────────┘
```

**Option 2**: Use [`StatePreparation`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.library.StatePreparation) directly instead of `initialize`:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import StatePreparation

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.append(StatePreparation('11'), [0, 1])
circuit.draw()
```

```
     ┌─────────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                        ├
     │  State Preparation(1,1) │
q_1: ┤1                        ├
     └─────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! By the way, I tried your Option 1 in the IBM system and it says "The instruction initialize on qubits is not supported by the target system. Circuits that do not match the target hardware definition are no longer supported after March 4, 2024." Guess there is only option 2, then? Is StatePreparation really just initialize without the reset in front?

Comment: Also, if I run "backend.supported_instructions", it has "reset" in the list. Why is this?

Comment: 'The instruction state_preparation on qubits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) is not supported by the target system. Circuits that do not match the target hardware definition are no longer supported after March 4, 2024'. It seems both initialize and StatePreparation do not work?